# Laravel : Doesn't have a default value - KeyProduct with Faker

Tags: php, database, laravel, join, faker

I can't add a keyproduct when i'm creating a new product.
I get the error `` SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'category_id' doesn't have a default value (SQL: insert into `products` (`activation_key`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (57394cd3-54f8-3e95-a951-e11f029fa0f5, 2020-05-27 17:09:08, 2020-05-27 17:09:08)) ``
I don't know why, it asks me that.

**What I tried :**

`category_id` is my first column that i'm adding in my table. If I put `->nullable()` to `category_id` , I get the same error with name that is the next column in my table.

This is imy code :

ProductController

```
  public function store(Request $request)
    {

        $inputs = $request->except('_token');
        $quantity = $inputs['quantity'];
        factory(KeyProduct::class, $quantity)->create();

 foreach ($inputs as $key => $value) {
            $home->$key = $value;
        }

        $home->image=$path;
        $home->save();
        return redirect('admin/gamelist');
}
```

Product_table

```
 Schema::create('products', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->integer('category_id')->unsigned();
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('image')->nullable();
            $table->string('activation_key')->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

KeyProduct_table.php

```
         Schema::create('key_products', function (Blueprint $table) {
           
             $table->increments('id');
             $table->string('activation_key');


             $table->timestamps();
         });
```

Keyproduct.php

```
 public function products()
    {
        return $this->HasOne('App\Product')->withPivot('quantity');
    }
```

Product.php

```
class Product extends Model
{
    public function categories()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Category', 'category_id');
    }
    
    public function keyProduct()
    {
        return $this->HasOne('App\KeyProduct');
    }

    protected $fillable = ['quantity'];
}
```

KeyProductFactory.php

```
use App\KeyProduct;
use App\Product;

$factory->define(KeyProduct::class, function (Faker $faker) {

    $product = factory(Product::class)->create();
    return [
            'activation_key' => $product->activation_key,
    
    ];
});
```

ProductFactory.php

```
use App\Product;
use Faker\Generator as Faker;

$factory->define(Product::class, function (Faker $faker) {
    return [
        'activation_key' => $faker->uuid
    ];
});
```

CategoryFactory

```
use App\Category;
use Faker\Generator as Faker;

$factory->define(Category::class, function (Faker $faker) {
    return [
        'activation_key' => $faker->uuid
    ];
});
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

It fails because the product is created without you setting that category_id or name at the time of creation. Make them nullable() or change your creation method accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

In your SQL you provided values for "activation_key", "updated_at" and "created_at" columns only, so other fields must satisfy at least one statement:

1. have an AUTO_INCREMENT option;
2. have a DEFAULT value;
3. allow NULL values.

You haven't provided enough data to complete the query.

Answer (score 0):

Add more `$fillable`s to your `Product.php` Model. By looking at your migrations it should look like this:

```php
protected $fillable = [
    'category_id', 'name', 'image', 'activation_key', 'quantity'
];
```